# Frame all the content

Tags: decorations

I am looking for the way of creating one border frame around everything I have.

Something like `standalone` class, but an outline insted of cropping. I would also like to manage margins, line thickness and its color.

Important to have the settings in the preambule, so I won't need to use, say `\begin{tikzpicture}...` for the framed content. It should frame everything automatically.

Here is how it should look like

```
\documentclass{article}

%%% Кւԍ⌡₭ϝძη₲₭⫳ძ⨍∈ηԌ <=== something code for the frame

\begin{document}
$$ 2+2=4 $$
My beautiful text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm... really your document is one page (with a number in the bottom, a lot of blank space, etc.). How should the code know that you want only the text you marked? I mean, I think that the objective is not well defined. (Why not using a `\fbox{\begin{minipage}...` thing, or better, [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en)?)

Comment: Page numbering can be removed. It is also possible to use `standalone` class if it helps.

Comment: Maybe you can add a `\begin{rcolorbox}` with `\AtBeginDocument` and the corresponding `\end...` at the end. Just to give a hint, no time now ;-)

Comment: There should not be anything related to the frame inside `document` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggest by @MadyYuvi use the `framed` package but apply it to the whole document.

```
% framedprob.tex  SE 546288

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{\begin{framed}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{framed}}
\begin{document}
%\begin{framed}
\[
 2+2=4 
\]
My beautiful text.

\lipsum[1-7]
%\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

The `framed` package does enable you to change the width (and color?) of the framing lines but that requires delving into the package internals. Perhaps ask another question about this; Donald Arseneau, the creator of `framed`, is a contributor to SE.

Comment: Thank you so much! What about lack of abilities to modify settings in `framed` package, I can simply use `mdframed`

Comment: @antshar If `mdframed` works for you then use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm undeleting my answer just for the record. I didn't understand what you wanted but for sure `tikz`, `tikzpagenodes` and `atbegshi` packages will allow you to do what you want (and a lot of configuration is possible there).

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

\NewDocumentCommand\StartFrame{}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw (current page text area.north west) rectangle (current page text area.south east);
}

\NewDocumentCommand\EndFrame{}{
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\StartFrame\EndFrame}}

\begin{document}

    \[ 2+2=4 \]
    My beautiful text

\end{document}
```

[image: Tikz frame]

If you want to limit your frame to the actual content, then `tcolorbox` may be a good choice and it is highly (and easily) customizable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\NewDocumentCommand\StartFrame{}{
    \begin{tcolorbox}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\EndFrame{}{
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

%\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\StartFrame\EndFrame}}
\AtBeginDocument{\StartFrame}
\AtEndDocument{\EndFrame}
\begin{document}

    \[ 2+2=4 \]
    My beautiful text

\end{document}
```

I hope you don't mind me adding these options to the voted answer.

[image: tcolorbox frame]

Comment: I need a frame that would be only around the contend, not the whole page.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I misunderstood. I remove my "answer".

Comment: I recall the first usage of `AtBeginDocument` from you. Edited answer is what I needed, great to find out about `tcolorbox`

Comment: I discovered it a few days ago and I really like it. I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct manner, then simply try with the `framed.sty` package, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{framed}


\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
\[
 2+2=4 
\]
My beautiful text
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong....

Comment: The requester is asking for all configuration to be in and only in the preamble.